# How to know json structure of a big java object?

Tags: java, json, jsonconvert

I hava a pojo with lots of classes attached to it. Wanted to know the JSON structure to be passed to the API.

Is there any way to create the json structure (with some fake data)?

**Example**:

```
public class Staff {

    private String personName;
    private Salary salary;
    private String[] position;              //  Array
    private List<Department> department;            //  List
    private Map<String, Address> addressMap; //  Map

    // getters & setters of those too.
}
```

- The `Department` has more number of POJOs within it (person joining to the department data)
- `Salary` has rivisions of each designations.
- so and so.

I am trying to get a JSON struture of this without creating it manually.

**Something like this (Expected output)**

```
{
    "person_name": "person_name",
    "salary": {
        "joining_salary": "0",
        "designation": {
            "joining_designation": "joining_designation",
            "some_data": "some_data"......
        }
    },
    "department": {
        "current_department": {
            "latitude": 59.331132099999998,
            "longitude": 18.066796700000001,
            "address": {
                "address_line": "address_line",
                "city_name": "city_name",
                "zip_code": "zip_code",
                "country_code": "co" ....> Restricted to 2 charactors
            }
        }
    },
    "some_other": [
        "...."
    ],
    "some": "some"
}
```

Comment: You could use a tool like swagger/openapi to generate this output for you.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `com.google.code.gson` library

Maven dependency is as below

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
    <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
    <version>2.8.6</version>
</dependency>
```

You can try the following,

```
Staff staff = new Staff();
// create your objects as required

Gson gson = new Gson();
// below jsonString will have the JSON structure of staff Object
String jsonString = gson.toJson(staff)
```

Comment: Oh ok, let me see. Thank you 
(I have edited my question by the way)

Comment: Nope @Saad, it does not work. I do not have a json with me. Gson will print the Json if I privide the data. right? I do not have any data with me / I do not know the Json structue to provide the data. I need to know the structure so that I can privide the data filled json.

Comment: Why don't you use the sample data which you have given in your question when creating the java objects. Once you have created the Java objects, using Gson you can create a JSON string. Once you have the JSON string you can replace the data in it later as required.

Comment: Hmm. It has a lot!. And there are multiple POJOs to do. I just provided a samle data to understand the expected result. Of course, I must have to try with some sample data, but thought to search/ask before I do so.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer using special and very powerful tool called “Jackson”

It can convert in both directions POJO -> JSON and JSON -> POJO

It also works with other input formats such as YAML etc

The usage is simple;

```
// Creates default JSON mapper
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper(); 

// Initialize your root object (it could be not necessarily “Stuff”) 
// including all nested classes and fields. Any dummy data is 
// applicable for your purposes.
Staff staff = new Staff(); 

// Write object to JSON in file:
mapper.writeValue(new File("c:\\staff.json"), staff);
```

[Jackson Dependency](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-databind/2.12.0) in Maven Repo

Answer (score 0):

you can use the gson, fastjson or Jackson
https://www.2json.net/article/45